# Javascript RegEx Not Working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following javascript code:

```
    function checkLegalYear() {
        var val = "02/2010"; 

        if (val != '') {
           var regEx = new RegExp("^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/\d{4}$", "g");

            if (regEx.test(val)) {
               //do something
            }
            else {
               //do something
            }
        }
    }
```

However, my regEx test always returns false for any value I pass (02/2010).  Is there something wrong in my code?  I've tried this code on various javascript editors online and it works fine.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Because you're creating your regular expression from a string, you have to double-up your backslashes:

```
var regEx = new RegExp("^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/\\d{4}$", "g");
```

When you start with a string, you have to account for the fact that the regular expression will first be parsed as such — that is, as a JavaScript string constant. The syntax for string constants doesn't know anything about regular expressions, and it has its own uses for backslash characters. Thus by the time the parser is done with your regular expression strings, it will look a lot different than it does when you look at your source code. Your source string looks like

```
"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/\d{4}$"
```

but after the string parse it's

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/d{4}$
```

Note that `\d` is now just `d`.

By doubling the backslash characters, you're telling the string parser that you want single actual backslashes in the string value.

There's really no reason here not to use regular expression syntax instead:

```
var regEx = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{4}$/g;
```

*edit* — I also notice that there's an embedded "/" character, which has to be quoted if you use regex syntax.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks so much; will accept when time limit is up.

Comment: The second solution is wrong, that / needs to be escaped. `...0-2])\/\d{4...`

Comment: I went to fix it after I commented and saw you changed it. Just took quick.

Comment: "There's really no reason here not to use regular expression syntax instead"

What if you want to concatenate your expressions? One from a library surrounded by other things?

Comment: var regex1 = RegExp('^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1](\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)d{4}$','g');

var str1 = '16/12/2018';

console.log(regex1.test(str1));
// expected output: true

When I test in regex101, 16/12/2018, returns true, but when I use it in my javascript file, ity always return false, why?

Comment: @RahulSharma because you're making your regular expression from a *string* instead of a regular expression literal.

Comment: @Pointy how should I handle it? I am confused.

Comment: @RahulSharma I added some more explanatory text.

Comment: @Pointy Yes sir. I did read. 

I implemented the following: 

var regex = /^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)d{4}$/g
regex.test(’16/12/2018’)

This also returns false every time.

This regex tries to test if date is of dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: @RahulSharma at the end of your regex, `d{4}` should be `\d{4}`. Also you *probably* don't need the "g" flag.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @Pointy.

Comment: Thanks a ton! never would've guessed this. Was plagued by this issue for an hour aahhhh

Comment: Thanks, just wasted 30 minutes on this..

Comment: shouldnt it be a bug that in string it doesnt recognize the escape sequence for \s but for \\ its okay

Comment: @MinhajulAnwar well JavaScript string constant syntax *does* "recognize" `\s`, but it doesn't mean anything special so it treats it as "s".