# regexp match only string without characters before and after

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I use javascript.
I need to match a string that would be like this (if I had to describe it with real words):

**(NOTHING before) + (only ONE word, not optional) + (".couleur" (it is a "fixed" word)) + (only ONE OPTIONAL SPACE) + ("=" (fixed word)) + (only ONE OPTIONAL SPACE) + (either the word "vert" or "violet" or "orange") + (NOTHING after)**

I tried this :

```
   var re1='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'; 
   var re2='(\\.)'; 
   var re3='(couleur)'; 
   var re4='(\\s?)';    
   var re5='(=)';   
   var re6='(\\s?)';    
   var re7='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'; 

   var p = new RegExp(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7,["i"]);
```

But I don't find how to avoid matching when there is something BEFORE and something AFTER my string, and I don't know how to check if the last part is "vert" "orange" or "violet" to match it.

EDIT: here are some string that would match :

```
"test.couleur = vert" 
"te.couleur = violet"
```

and here are some string that wouldn't match:

```
" test.couleur = vert" (space before)
" e tdk.couleur = vert" (something before the first word)
"tdl.couleur = vert e" (something after the last word)
"tdk.couleur = gris" (gris is not "vert" or "orange" or "violet")
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: change `re7` to `var re7='(?:vert|orange|violet)'; ` then add anchors like `var p = new RegExp("^" + re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7 + "$","i");`

Comment: Made it and it worked, thanks a lot! @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression should fit your needs:

```
var re = new RegExp('^\\w+\\.couleur\\s?=\\s?(vert|violet|orange)$', 'i');
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/wK1iC4/2).

Comment: There is some serious issue with the solution in this answer (`new RegExp('^\w+\.couleur\s?=\s?(vert|violet|orange)$', 'i')`). [Backslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769964/backslashes-regular-expression-javascript).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: you're right... I did just corrected it... When answer was accepted it was working because I did not use RegExp, but inline pattern /.../. I changet it to better reflect OP question, using RegExp...

Comment: forgot to mention that i used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521572/javascript-regex-not-working this answer to make it work. But that was a good regexp anyway @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Good. BTW, "should-fit-your-needs" is a type of explanation I do not understand, but most SO users are happy with it. No idea why. The other answer is identical, anyway :) Good day.

Comment: ??? It's not an "explanation", it's an "introduction"... @timolawl answer is similar, but *later*... :-)

Comment: @MarcoS how can I change your regexp to change "w+" at the beggining with a js variable ? Can't make it work actually...

Comment: `var re = new RegExp('^' + jsVariable + '\\.couleur\\s?=\\s?(vert|violet|orange)$', 'i');`

Comment: @MarcoS Yes, and I learned a valuable lesson from this. I already had my solution but I decided to write out a fully functional example before submitting it. If I had simply submitted the one liner first, it's arguable who would have been first :).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var regex = /^\w+\.couleur\s?=\s?(vert|violet|orange)$/i;
```

Here it is in action with all your test strings:

```js
var strArr = ["test.couleur = vert", "te.couleur = violet", " test.couleur = vert", "  e tdk.couleur = vert", "tdl.couleur = vert e", "tdk.couleur = gris"];

var regex = /^\w+\.couleur\s?=\s?(vert|violet|orange)$/i;

strArr.forEach(function(str) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', str + ": " + regex.test(str));
});
```