# Javascript function RegExp.test() always returns false for my regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I saw some questions here but no one works for me. This regex should only accept phone numbers.
I need to use expressions as strings because I need to get them from a data- attribute.

This is the code:

```
    $('.valid_mobile').change(function(event) {

    var rex = '^0\d{10}$';
    var message = 'This is not a valid mobile phone number.';

    var text = $(this).val();
    var regex = new RegExp(rex);

    if (! regex.test(text))
    {
        alert(message);
        $(this).val('');
    }
    console.log(regex.test(text));
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769964/backslashes-regular-expression-javascript  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521572/javascript-regex-not-working => `var rex = '^0\\d{10}$';` or `var regex = /^0\d{10}$/`

Comment: Thanks. Then I need double slashes!!!
but why?

Comment: You need double backslashes because in C strings, a backslash is used to define escape sequences. A literal ``\`` is defined as ``\\``, and that is the kind of the backslash a regex engine requires to define shorthand character classes.